# Settingg alert for monitoring by nrpe

Tags: linux, nagios

I am testing nagios and nrpe like this

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       nrpeserver.com
        service_description             check_disk
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_disk
        notification_period     24x7
        notification_interval   30

}
```

then I tested.

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H nrpeserver.com  -c check_disk
```

OK,It works.

Now I want to add warning point to this.

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H nrpeserver.com  -c check_disk -w 10
```

it shows
`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe: invalid option -- 'w'`

I tried this too

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 54.71.164.129  -c "check_disk -w 10"
```

shows error like this

```
NRPE: Command 'check_disk -w 10' not defined
```

How can I set warning point to nrpe ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-w` and `-c` are flags for the `check_disk` command but you're passing them in to the `check_nrpe` command.

You need to pass in the warning and critical levels as arguments for `check_disk` with the `-a` flag and quotes like this:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 54.71.164.129 -t 30 -c check_disk -a '-w 5 -c 10'
```